# Inverter Pilha Dinâmica

Tags: c, stack, dinâmico

alguém poderia me auxiliar com essa pilha?
O objetivo é criar uma função que inverta os valores da pilha, tentei fazer isso utilização a função Inverter() do código abaixo, porém ela não está funcionando, quando executo simplesmente encerra o código. Caso alguém tenha alguma ideia, posso estar fazendo a alocação errada...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct elemento{
    int valor;
    struct Elemento *anterior;
} Elemento;

typedef struct pilha{
    struct Elemento *topo;
    int tam;
} Pilha;

Pilha *criaPilha(){
    Pilha *p = (Pilha*)malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    p->topo = NULL;
    p->tam = 0;
    return p;
}
int vazia(Pilha *p){
    if(p->topo == NULL){
    return -1;
    } else {
    return 2;
    }
}
void empilha(Pilha * p, int v){
Elemento *e = (Elemento*)malloc(sizeof(Elemento));
e->valor = v;
    if(vazia(p) == 2){
        e->anterior = p->topo;
    }
    p->topo = e;
    p->tam++;
}
int desempilha(Pilha *p){
    int val;
    if(vazia(p) == 2){
        Elemento *aux;
        aux = p->topo; //Crio uma variável para ajudar a acessar o elemento anterior armazenado no topo;
        val = aux->valor;
        p->topo = aux->anterior; //Topo passa a ser o elemento anterior
        p->tam--;
        free(aux);
        return val;
    }
}

void maiorMenorMedia(Pilha *p, int *maior, int *media,int *menor){
int r = 0, cont = 0; 
int soma = 0;
int menorc = 99999;
int maiorc = -99999;
while(p->topo != NULL){
    r = desempilha(p);
    if(r > maiorc){
        maiorc = r;
    }
    if(r < menorc){
        menorc = r;
    }
    cont++;
    soma += r;
}
*maior = maiorc;
*media = (soma/cont);
*menor = menorc;
}

int maisElementos(Pilha *a, Pilha *b){
if(a->tam > b->tam){
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
}
Pilha * inverter(Pilha *pilha){
    int value;
    Pilha * aux = criaPilha();
    while(pilha->topo != 0){
        value = desempilha(pilha);
        empilha(aux, value);
    }
    return aux;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Pilha *pteste = criaPilha();
    empilha(pteste, 15);
    empilha(pteste, 16);
    empilha(pteste, 17); 
    printf("%d\n", pteste->tam);

    int maior, media, menor;

    maiorMenorMedia(pteste, &maior, &media, &menor);
    printf("Maior: %d\n", maior);
    printf("menor: %d\n", menor);
    printf("media: %d\n", media);

Pilha *a = criaPilha();
Pilha *b = criaPilha();
empilha(a, 15);
empilha(a, 16);
empilha(b, 15); 
empilha(b, 16);
empilha(b, 17);
empilha(b, 18);

if(maisElementos(a,b) == 1){
    printf("Pilha A tem mais elementos\n");
}else{
    printf("Pilha B tem mais elementos\n");
}

Pilha *z = criaPilha();
z = inverter(b);
int x = 0;
x = desempilha(z);
printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: O resto das funções estão bem? Testei e há um problema qualquer na função desempilha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem vários pormenores que não estão certos embora a lógica em si esteja certa. Aconselho sempre a olhar com **muita atenção** para os avisos do compilador pois quase sempre são erros e coisas que deve corrigir.

- Na definição da estrutura `elemento`:

  ```
  typedef struct elemento{
      int valor;
      struct Elemento *anterior;
      //     ^---
  } Elemento;
  ```

  O `typedef` só é finalizado no fim da instrução logo não pode usar o nome definido por ele no meio da estrutura. Para alem disso o `typedef` é feito para poder utilizar apenas `Elemento` e não `struct Elemento`. Por isso o correto é:

  ```
  typedef struct elemento{
      int valor;
      struct elemento *anterior;
      //     ^---
  } Elemento;
  ```
- Logo na estrutura seguinte tem o mesmo problema:

  ```
  typedef struct pilha {
      struct Elemento *topo;
  //      ^-----^
      int tam;
  } Pilha;
  ```

  Em que `struct Elemento` deve ser apenas `Elemento` pois esse sim corresponde ao `typedef` que fez anteriormente.
- O `empilha` não coloca o ultimo elemento a apontar para `NULL` e por isso o teste se a pilha está fazia na função `vazia`, o `if(p->topo == NULL) {` não funciona como esperado e começa a aceder a valores fora da memoria que declarou.

  Para corrigir basta afetar o `e->anterior = NULL` quando é o primeiro elemento da Pilha:

  ```
  void empilha(Pilha * p, int v) {
      Elemento *e = (Elemento*)malloc(sizeof(Elemento));
      e->valor = v;
      if(vazia(p) == 2) {
          e->anterior = p->topo;
      }
      else { //se está vazia porque é o primeiro
          e->anterior = NULL; //mete esse a apontar para NULL
      }
      p->topo = e;
      p->tam++;
  }
  ```

Tem muitas outras coisas a melhorar mas deixo apenas as mais importantes:

- Evite utilizar números soltos (mágicos) tal como `if (vazia(p) == 2)`. Isto torna-se bem difícil de ler e fácil de errar. Pode utilizar `#define` para definir constantes que facilita.
- Defina retornos das funções para todos os caminhos possíveis. Na sua função `desempilha` caso a pilha esteja vazia não tem nenhum retorno especificado.